# How many characters can "javascript var keyword" store?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I want to create a variable to store the value of textarea by using *var* keyword. But I don't know exactly about the maximum characters which **"var"** can store.

Can you help me?

Comment: There is no such limit in JS.

Comment: To be more precise the ECMAScript Specification does not specify the max. So it will depend on the implementation (e.G. your browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such limit. The maximum limit i think is gonna be based on the browser or in short browser specific!